# MySQL: Use one table to fill another quickly

Tags: mysql

I am running MySQL (new language for me) and am trying to merge two tables as described ad nauseam on this forum.  I took what seems to be the most popular answer from another thread, and it works:

```
  ALTER TABLE table1 ADD col3 varchar( 30 ) NOT NULL; 
  UPDATE table1,table2
  SET table1.col3=table2.col3
  WHERE table1.col1 = table2.col1 AND table1.col2 = table2.col2
```

The problem is performance -- this takes 15 s to update 500 records, and apparently hours to update ~50k records (on my Macbook).  How can I make this MUCH faster?

Comment: Are `col1` and `col2` of both tables indexed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write this query using an explicit `join`:

```
UPDATE table1 join
       table2
       ON table1.col1 = table2.col1 AND table1.col2 = table2.col2
    SET table1.col3 = table2.col3;
```

But either way, you need an index.  I would recommend `table2(col1, col2, col3)`:

```
create index idx_table2_col1_col2_col3 on table2(col1, col2, col3);
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you!  Indexing was the missing link, the 50k records ran in 20 s now.  Will accept your answer.

Comment: If mysql support index only scans, you might actually do better with the matching indexes on both tables.  Put the column with the highest cardinality first in the index.  I have seen that trick boost performance by as much as 40 times over what is attained by putting the lowest cardinality first.  If there are only a few tens of thousands of rows the operation should take only a minute or so.